# Creating Node.js API Framework with API Registration

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, api-key

How do I add API Registration/Billing into my ExpressJS and/or node-restify Server ?
(something similar to http://django-rest-framework.org/ in Python world ? )

I've got the API server running using ExpressJS now (maybe will convert to node-restify soon).

I'd like users to register API keys and to pay for high usage.

What libraries are available to simplify my task ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Node-Restify is a breeze to add "middleware" to provide any specialist behaviours to the request-response pipeline. These can be place before, in, or after route handlers run. From your question I would place these before routes run to validate/bill for the URI/HTTP method access. The docs are good too in this area.

```
server.use(function (req, res, next){ // do your thing here, call next if happy });
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a 3rd party service - espcially if you intend to charge for API use as they will handle measuring usage and billing. Some of these services only charge if you charge so that's a good start.  There are quire a few so I'll list my favorite which is [Mashape](http://mashape.com) - really nice UI, no charge for free API use else 25% of what you charge. It's a good starter one since there is no cost outlay. There are others good ones such as Mashery, 3Scale, Apigee and more. You can seach for "Mashape alternatives" in Google to get the others.

As far as rolling your own check out [ApiAxle](http://apiaxle.com). It doesn't have an integrated billing but it is Node based, offer useage stats, rate limiting, caching and has an API to generate keys, etc... Combined with something like [Stripe](http://stripe.com) you could create your own billing system.